# How to know about the methods present inside a python module?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python, i have a confusion about when we import a module, e.g. import os or any other module, how to know the available methods in each of the module i have imported? Please help.

Comment: Or just [RTFM](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
import(os)
help(os)
```

That will give you a human-readable help page.  Or to get just the function and class names:

```
dir(os)
```

Comment: You're welcome.  If this answer helped you, please accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left of it.